# JQuery animate() duration only applies to some CSS rules

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm trying to animate the position of an absolutely positioned element, but the `animate()` duration parameter only seems to apply to *some* CSS rules, and not to others. For `width`, `height`, `top` and `left` the animation happens `fast`, whatever value I use for the duration.

```
    // add the post to the grid
    var p = $('.post-bucket .post:nth-of-type(1)').clone();
    p.appendTo('.grid');

    // animate it
    p.animate(
        {
            width: '200px',
            'padding-top': '200px',
            opacity: 1.0,3
            top: '20px',
        },
        1200,
        function() {}
    );
```

If I change the duration to 5000, the opacity changes correctly over a 5s period, but the other changes animate in about 200s.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look like that

```
p.animate(
  {
    width: '200px',
    paddingTop: '200px',
    opacity: '1.0',
    top: '20px',
  },
  1200,
  function() {
    alert('done');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it works fine as you can see in the demo. It takes the same 5000ms for animating all the properties.

```js
    $("div").click(function(){
        // animate it
        $("p").animate(
            {
                width: '200px',
                'padding-top': '200px',
                opacity: 1.0,
                top: '20px',
            },
            5000,
            function() {}
        );    
    });
```

```css
p {
 background: red;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Paragraph here</p>
<div>click me</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers, but my issue was that I had a lingering style rule on the element:

`transition: all 0.2s ease;`

I find it odd that a CSS rule here overrides an explicit JavaScript rule but there you go.